# Why doesn't Angular i18n work properly in my project?

Tags: angular, angular-i18n, angular-localize

I am implementing an i18n for a personal project which uses Atomic Design for components. So far I haven't encountered any problems (and I am pretty new to Angular), but for the last couple of days I've lost sleep on this topic. Trying to extract the i18n properties has proven to be more troublesome than it's been worth it so far.

**THE PROBLEM**

Running `ng extract-i18n` only works for `app.component.html` and not for the subfolders.

I've tried this also in a barebone project:

```
ng new testProject
cd testProject
npm i @angular/localize
ng generate component testA
ng generate component components/testB
```

Now for a bit of grunt work:

Modify each component to include a simple i18n declaration.
I used a these in respective files:

```html
<p i18n="@@app">app</p> <!--@ src/app/app.component.html-->
<p i18n="@@testA">test-a works!</p> <!--@ src/app/test-a/test-a.component.html-->
<p i18n="@@testB">test-b works!</p> <!-- src/app/components/test-b.component.html-->
```

Finally, run `ng extract-i18n --outputPath="src/i18n"` and you should see `src/i18n/messages.json`. However, if you notice bellow, only `@@app` is being localized, and the rest aren't.

```
{
  "locale": "en-US",
  "translations": {
    "app": "app"
  }
}
```

**HOWEVER**

During my search for a solution to this problem, I found this [demo project](https://github.com/PhraseApp-Blog/angular-i18n-2022).
As you can notice, it also has an Atomic Design structure (or at least a version of it).

[image]

```
git clone https://github.com/PhraseApp-Blog/angular-i18n-2022
cd angular-i18n-2022
npm install
ng extract-i18n --outputPath="src/locale" --format="json"
```

The only modified file is the nested `src/app/layout/navbar/navbar.component.html` to test my theory, everything else comes from the demo project.

The `messages.json` output:

```
{
  "locale": "en-CA",
  "translations": {
    "1475737827206181859": "Demo companion app for\n  <a href=\"{$PH}\">Phrase blog</a>\n  post.\n  <a href=\"{$PH_1}\">Made with Angular</a>.",
    "navbar": "navbar",
    "615967567956853879": "azcadea logo",
    "7285274704628585281": "azcadea",
    "2821179408673282599": "Home",
    "1726363342938046830": "About",
    "8856905278208146821": " {$ICU} ",
    "7185053985224017078": "{VAR_PLURAL, plural, =0 {Sold out} =1 {Available at 1 outlet} other {Available at\n          {INTERPOLATION} outlets}}",
    "4481891408571585417": " Add to cart ",
    "6223458566712133696": "Image of {$PH}"
  }
}
```

**SUMMARY**

I tried comparing my config files to the demo project (`angular.json, package.json, tsconfig.app.json, tsconfig.json, tsconfig.spec.json`). I've gone over any possible documentation I could find, back and forth. The only notable differences I could find were the angular version `latest vs 13.3.0` and the module version in `tsconfig.json` `latest vs es2017/es2022`.

My hunch says it's something very simple and I'm just missing a property/path or some declaration to scan the subfolders and not just the app folder. But I've found no indication how to enable this.

Any advice or feedback would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

***As Volodymyr Mishyn's comment suggests, the component needs to be referenced in other components/modules, for the i18n to be extracted***

Therefore:

The example I give at the top, creating new components, doesn't work as the newly generated components don't get automatically referenced anywhere, until you import them in the respective module.

What I missed:

In the demo project, when you generate a component, it automatically gets added to `app.module.ts` and therefore instantly can be i18n-ed.

In my project, this behavior is not default, so the new component is detached and therefore not i18n-ed - as intended.
This may be due to different Angular versions, but that's just speculation on my part.

What confuses me:

I added i18n to my project in the header component `src/app/components/header/header.component.html`.
Obviously it was referenced and built, yet until now the extraction wasn't working. The best I can describe this behavior is that the extraction pipeline was somehow blocked, but it's a weak explanation that holds little merit.

Comment: I got the same problem, but my components are standalone and referenced by several routing modules, is there any new info on how to fix it besides declaring everything in one giant module?

Comment: @robin check your angular.json if "localize" is on in the builder section. other than that I don't know, I gave up on i18n the project. might use ngx-translate in the future

Comment: localize is in angular.json and translation works for all but 2 components, but thank you anyway:)

Comment: Try putting the components on highest level possible. (app.component.html) and see if ng extract-i18n does the job.
Sidenote: My friend showed me a production grade angular project and they are using ngx-translate. I am assuming it's because extract-i18n behaves so strangely.
Judging from the info I gathered researching this, I don't like the way it works. It generates a duplicate build for another language. I've experimented with just fetching the translations with the backend and it feels way smoother than whatever they're doing. Let me know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your components used somewhere?
like in other components or routing.

I got the theory, that the problem is related to tree-shaking.

your components don't finish up in the final bundle during build, and so no i18n got extracted.

I tried this theory on my pet project

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FirstComponent } from './first/first.component';
// import { SecondComponent } from './second/second.component'; Commented this line

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
  // { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent }, and this line
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/home',
  },
];
```

and running

```
ng extract-i18n --output-path src/locale
```

omits i18n strings from SecondComponent in result file

So try using your components somewhere.

Comment: So, the strangest thing happened. Inspired by your advice, I reverted all the changes in my code and proceeded to experiment with your approach. Then the messages simply started being extracted for no explicable reasons. I even created a new component that's not referenced everywhere, and that part was correct about your assumption. 

I will update the question with my findings and accept your answer as correct.